# Using JWT from classic ASP site for authentication on a .NET 6 web app

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP site that I want to use as an issuer for a JWT to authenticate users on a .NET core web app.

I am trying to do this so that I could eventually migrate all the features/reports ETC gradually over to the .NET core site as obviously classic ASP is archaic. There is far too much content to just start over in .NET so that is why I was hoping to go with this approach.

My idea is that if the user is logged in on the classic ASP site (has a session) that a JWT would be returned with the users information User Id, Name ETC.

I have a page on the classic ASP site that will generate a JWT but I am very unfamiliar with setting up a .NET core project.

I want to get a JWT from https://localhost:44300/auth.asp and if its valid then the user should be able to navigate the .net core website.

One issue I noticed while playing around(just doing an http request in a controller) is that i have to attach the classic ASP session cookie to the request in order for the classic ASP site to recognize that I am actually logged in to it and all.

The references I have seen are for giving out a JWT for an API so I'm not really sure what to do.

I have attempted to session share via storing the session in the DB but it seems like that path would require a big headache with managing the session across the two different websites/technologies.

Comment: That is the problem is you could make it work but its going to require that big headache to match everything up.  One key thing you need to know about ASP Classic Session is that you have to set the Application Pool to No Managed Code for it work, which upsets .NET because it prefers to manage the application pools dynamically.   So passing from one to the other is a bit tricky.  And like you said, you COULD technically use the database as a medium to pass the session data between programs, but God help you with that.